# Not able to access magento admin pannel

Tags: magento

i’m working on Magento, I did something wrong but, I don’t know what i need to do now. Coming to my issue,I changed url path in system->configation->advanced->admin->admin base url, from that point Magento admin panel is gone. i’m not able to access admin panel. now i removed that path from data base -> core_config_data.
as a result now i’m able to see login popup but after entering credentials i’m not able to see admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by removing merge from cpanel->app->cache. Thank you and hope this will used for someone